# How to create multiple password protected browser profiles on a windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, browser, profile

I've got multiple people using the same machine with the same user account. Assume that this is not possible to change and I won't get into the details why. The system has all Windows 10 pro features.

I'd like the users to be able to use their own profiles in the browser (other applications don't matter), with access protected by a password. I don't expect any serious security here - the password is really only to prevent accidental usage of the wrong profile and simple temptation to snoop. Ideally, I'd like the profile sync to work in that browser for each separate user.

There were some options that I looked at, but nothing seems to be actually available right now:

- Chrome's "new profile management" - this option seems to have existed in 2018/2019, but is removed now - setting a password on sync doesn't force password input on browser startup and the "exit and child lock" menu doesn't exist anymore
- ChromePW extension doesn't exist anymore
- Firefox doesn't seem to have password protection in standard profiles
- Firefox MasterPassword extension doesn't exist anymore
- I thought of various sandbox approaches, but it seems that Windows 10 sandbox doesn't really support persistent, named sandboxes; I could use sandboxie I guess, but that seems like a lot of work to setup and still leaves the question of password protection

I could force something with a password protected zip file containing profile, but I'm looking for something much simpler to operate.

I don't mind whether the solution works in Edge / Firefox / Chrome.

What are my options these days?

Comment: All browsers support this _(excl. IE and the old Edge, while Microsoft's new Chromium-based Edge does)_... in the Settings Menu, have each user set up their own profile with their email, and in order to switch profiles, the email account's passphrase must be entered.

Comment: I've tested it and no, the password is not required to change the profile.

Comment: I didn't realize that and thought it did... I'm not sure then. Don't use Sandboxie, unless you're familiar with it, as it's no longer supported by its community, and it's impossible to configure a browser to run correctly in Sandboxie without the knowledge of the community. It's a phenomenal piece of software but is too complex to figure out for browsers without community support since the man pages leave a lot to be desired.